# How to prevent namespace wrapper tags in SOAP wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I created a `wsdl` webservice with `cxf`.

Problem: both my request and response contain an extra wrapper element with the namespace.

Question: is it possible to prevent this wrapper element? Because for me it adds no value, and is just an additional element when others would use my webservice.

For example I'd like to reduce the `<com:MyNameOperation><MyNameReq>` hierarchie in the following example to be just one element, not two nested elements.

```
@WebService(name = "myname", serviceName = "myname", targetNamespace = "com.test")
publi class MySoapServlet {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "MyNameOperation")   
    @WebResult(name = "MyNameResult")
    public MyResponse getRsp(@WebParam(name = "MyNameReq") MyNameReq req) {
        //return...
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "MyNameResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MyNameResponse {
    private String name;
}
```

Resulting wsdl structure:

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:de="com.test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <!-- how can I omit this namespace element completely? -->
      <com:MyNameOperation>
         <MyNameReq>
            ...
         </MyNameReq>
      </com:MyNameOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <!-- how can I omit this namespace element completely? -->
      <ns2:MyNameResponse xmlns:ns2="com.test">
        <MyNameResult>
          <name>somevalue</name>
        </MyNameResult>
      </ns2:MyNameResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user parameterstyle BARE `@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE)`. However you cannot completely remove the 2 levels, since operation name is required to identify the operation. Updated class would look like as shown below

```
@WebService(name = "myname", serviceName = "myname", targetNamespace = "com.test")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE)
publi class MySoapServlet {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "MyNameOperation")   
    @WebResult(name = "MyNameResult")
    public MyResponse getRsp(@WebParam(name = "MyNameReq") MyNameReq req) {
        //return...
    }
}
```

The updated request xml would be.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:de="com.test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
         <com:MyNameReq>
            <name >data</name>
         </com:MyNameReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And response would be

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <!-- how can I omit this namespace element completely? -->
      <ns2:MyNameResult xmlns:ns2="com.test">
          <name>somevalue</name>
      </ns2:MyNameResult>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```