# remove a tag in soap response using CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mule, cxf

I am new to CXF. I am using CXF component in mulesoft to create Webservice. WebService is running successfully. But, I want to remove a  tag from response.
I have used @ResponseWrapper, @SoapBinding(ParameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE). but, these are not resolved my issue.
I have heared that, we can modify soap response(i.e remove  tag) by using Outintercepters. If it is can anybody help me to how to use interceptors and what phase we can modify the soap response to remove  tag..

Actual Soap Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns2:getMyresponse xmlns:ns2="http://myschema.com">
   <return>
    <errorcode>1</errorcode>
    <errormsg>notsuccesful</errorms>
   </return>
  </ns2:getMyresponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Evelope>
```

Expected Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns2:getMyresponse xmlns:ns2="http://myschema.com">
    <errorcode>1</errorcode>
    <errormsg>notsuccesful</errorms>
  </ns2:getMyresponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Evelope>
```

SEI class is:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:com.test", name = "GetActivityListInterface")

public interface GetActivityListInterface {

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetMyActivities", targetNamespace = "urn:com.test", className = "com.test.beans.MyActivities")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetMyActivities", action = "urn:com.test/GetMyActivities")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetMyResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:com.test", className = "com.test.beans.GetMyResponse")
    public GetMyActivitiesResponse getMyActivities(
        @WebParam(name = "id", partName="id")
        java.lang.String id,
        @WebParam(name = "date", partName="date")
        java.lang.String date);
}
```

Comment: The question is more general, if you can be more specific with code snippet, the particular tag it would be easy for people to answer

Comment: Thansk Senthilkumar Annadurai for response.I have added expected and actual response can you please check once

Comment: Check if this resolves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503346/how-to-prevent-namespace-wrapper-tags-in-soap-wsdl/38509549#38509549

Comment: Please add the related SEI class and/or interface as well. The class and/or interface which has @WebService annotation

Comment: @Senthilkumar Annadurai I have added SEI class

Comment: @vtd-xml-author can you please specify how to use it.

Comment: I guess you are using generated GetMyActivitiesResponse class(when you didnt have parameterStyle as BARE). Could you include the GetMyActivitiesResponse class to the post

Answer (score 0):

Use an **XSL-T** to remove the tags that you want to remove from response xml.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please specify how to use it.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641681/remove-xml-tags-with-xslt** check out the example here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ResponseWrapper and use @WebResult. Like this

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:com.test", name = "GetActivityListInterface")

public interface GetActivityListInterface {

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetMyActivities", targetNamespace = "urn:com.test", className = "com.test.beans.MyActivities")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetMyActivities", action = "urn:com.test/GetMyActivities")
    @WebResult(name = "GetMyResponse", partName="GetMyResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:com.test")
    public GetMyActivitiesResponse getMyActivities(
        @WebParam(name = "id", partName="id")
        java.lang.String id,
        @WebParam(name = "date", partName="date")
        java.lang.String date);
}
```

Comment: yes , what you said is correct but , it will show "GetMyResponse" in place of <return> tag , but we need nothing in place of that , please check below for reference .

<soap:Body>
  <ns2:getMyresponse xmlns:ns2="http://myschema.com">
    <errorcode>1</errorcode>
    <errormsg>notsuccesful</errorms>
  </ns2:getMyresponse>
 </soap:Body>